# Excel: sort names by given values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had to do a little work with excel but I am stuck at the following point:

```
    A    B    C    D    E   F ....
1
2
3        "A"  1
4        "B"  0
5        "C"  1
6        "D"  2
7
8
9
```

My table looks something like this.
In `B3:B6` I do have 4 names, in `C3:C6`, I do have the corresponding scores.

Now, I would like to order the names by their given points and display them in `E3:E6`

I am not that familiar with excel so I am very happy for any help.

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: Highlight the cells. then on the data tab select sort. Then choose the column by which you want to sort.

Comment: Is this flexible? Can i change the content later on and everything happens automatically?

Comment: no for that you will need vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: but what about a formula where I do not change the order in b3:b6 but display it in d3:d6 ?

Comment: Will the data set size be set, or will the size be dynamic?

Comment: set. Only 4. I just do not want to create hundreds of IF-statements.

Comment: What about ties? does order matter there?

Comment: No, the order does not matter there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the numbers in order with Large Function:

```
=LARGE($C$3:$C$6,ROW(A1))
```

Put that in F3 and copy down 4.  It will list the numbers in order.

Then in E3 put this formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$3:$C$6)/($C$3:$C$6=F3),COUNTIF($F$3:F3,F3)))
```

Which looks up the corresponding name.

[image]